# The method getBuild() is undefined for the type MvcUriComponentsBuilder.MethodArgumentBuilder

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Problem on building URIs to Controllers and methods from views.
Using spring 4.1 ; My Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/produtos")
public class ProductsController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;

    @Transactional   
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView save(Product product){

        productDAO.save(product);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:produtos");
    }
```

And my JSP

```
    <form:form action="${spring:mvcUrl('PC#save').build()}" method="post" >
```

I get a error on JSP:

The method getBuild() is undefined for the type MvcUriComponentsBuilder.MethodArgumentBuilder

if i use the syntax http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates:

```
        <form:form action="${spring:mvcUrl(''PC#save'').build()}" method="post" >
```

appears to have no error on JSP, but in web:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/products/form.jsp (line: 20, column: 1) "${spring:mvcUrl(''PC#save'').build()}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${spring:mvcUrl(''PC#save'').build()}]
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:275)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:91)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1422)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1231)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:879)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1536)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1853)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:172)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I also try to delete JSP error on eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add a taglib
`<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>`

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.